# unable to call Service from lib function in hapijs

Tags: node.js

I am using hapijs and i am trying to save SMS logs to my mongodb database which are getting triggered from "Lib/NotificationManager.js".

```
 /*** SMS LOG TO DB ***/
                    var dataToSet = {
                        triggeredFrom : "XXX",
                        triggeredTo : "XXX",
                        message : smsOptions.Body,
                        messageType : type,
                        messageFor: "XXX",
                        variables : variableDetails,
                        response : res,
                    };
                    Service.MessageLogsService.addMessageLogsinsert(dataToSet, function (err, data) {
                    });
/*** SMS LOG TO DB ***/
```

I already included Service and Model to my NotificationManager.js files.

```
var Service = require('../Services');
var Models = require('../Models');
```

It through error

```
"Cannot read property 'addMessageLogsinsert' of undefined"
```

It is working fine if i am calling it from any controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried directly running query with the help of Model in the notificationManager.js as follow.

```
/*** SMS LOG TO DB ***/
                var dataToSet = {
                    triggeredFrom : "XXX",
                    triggeredTo : "XXX",
                    message : smsOptions.Body,
                    messageType : type,
                    messageFor: "XXX",
                    variables : variableDetails,
                    response : res,
                };
                Models.MessageLogs.collection.insert(dataToSet,function (err, data) {
                // Service.MessageLogsService.addMessageLogsinsert(dataToSet, function (err, data) {
                });
              /*** SMS LOG TO DB ***/
```

It works.

Comment: var Service = require('../Services');
var Models = require('../Models');

I tried to check above variables in console.log() and i found that Model included successfully but there is some problem in case of Service and it is empty.